# Get avg of cpu temp's as a one line script

Tags: bash, shell

I need to average the temperatures of the four cpu cores on my system. I am obtaining the temperatures of the individual cores using the command:
`sysctl -a | awk '/temperature/ {print $2;}'`

This spits out the following output:

```
    53.0C
    53.0C
    52.0C
    52.0C
```

I then pass this to sed and tr and with some script-fu I ended up with the following-one liner:

```
echo `sysctl -a | awk '/temperature/ {print $2;}' | sed s/C// | tr '\n' '+' | sed 's/\(.*\)+/\1/'` | bc`
```

which then results in:

`210`

I now simply need to divide `210/4` to get my average but am stumped on how to achieve this as an extension to the one-liner that I have already brewed up. And due to some other constraints, I need to keep this as a one-liner.

I am sure there's a simpler way to achieve what I am after, any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Add output of `sysctl -a | awk '/temperature/'` to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
sysctl -a | awk -F '[ C]' '/temperature/{sum+=$2} END{print sum/NF}'
```

Output:

```
52.5
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/?ref=binfind.com/web)

Comment: Thanks, especially for the very helpful link to the built-in vars.

Answer (score 1):

You can add parenthesis and division by 4 around your expression with:

```
 { echo -n "("; tr '\n' '+'; echo -n")/4"; }
```

The final result is:

```
echo `sysctl -a | awk '/temperature/ {print $2;}' | sed s/C// |  { echo -n "("; tr '\n' '+'; echo -n")/4"; } | sed 's/\(.*\)+/\1/'` | bc`
```